# Authenticate using Azure AD ASP.NET 5.0?

Tags: asp.net-core

Can someone help me how to authenticate with Azure AD with ASP.NET 5.0? I found this code for Katana but i do not know the equivalent in ASP.NET 5.0

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wtrealm = "http://myapps/testapp",
                MetadataAddress = "https://login.windows.net/34g988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd911db47/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml"
            });
```

Comment: Per an email thread we had, this will be available *very soon*. How soon is very soon? *VERY* soon :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a new implementation for cookie based authentication in ASP.NET 5.0, the examples can be found on the official [MicroSoft ASP.NET Security GitHub page](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/samples/CookieSample/Startup.cs)

First you will need to add the authentication library as a dependency in your project.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-*",
```

Look at the lines:

```
 using Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies;
```

and:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
});

app.Run(async context =>
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.User.Identity.Name))
    {
        var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(
            new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "bob") 
            }
        ));

        context.Authentication.SignIn(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                                      user);
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello First timer");
        return;
    }

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello old timer");
});
```

This should come before app.UseMvc() in an MVC 6 web app.
I hope this helps? Let me know if this does not meet your requirements and I will try to clear up any points :)